# Ruby deserializing YAML

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml, deserialization

I'm working with DelayedJob and I need to override a method that I *thought* was being used when an object is deserialized from YAML: `self.yaml_new` (defined in in `delayed/serialization/active_record`)

My impression was that when YAML deserialized some data, it would call the `yaml_new` method on the class of the type of that data

DJ's `yaml_new` method fetches the object from the database using the passed in id

I'm unable to achieve this behaviour with my own classes.  When I set a `self.yaml_new` method on a class and try to `YAML.load` on a serialized instance, it doesn't seem to call `yaml_new` so I must obviously be mistaken.

What then is this method for?

Searching for `yaml_new` doesn't yield much (just API docs of other people using it).  So I'm wondering what exactly this method is.

I figured `yaml_new` would be some hook method called when an object is found of some type if that method existed on the class.  But again I can't actually get this to work.  Below is a sample:

```
class B
  def self.yaml_new(klass, tag, val)
    puts "I'm in yaml new!"
  end
end

b = B.new
YAML.load b.to_yaml    # expected "I'm in yaml new!" got nothing
```

**updates**

So after playing around in my Rails application, it appears that `yaml_new` *does* actually get called from `YAML.load`.  I have a file in there like so:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base

    def self.yaml_new(klass, tag, val)
      puts "\n\n yaml_new!!!\n\n"
      klass.find(val['attributes']['id'])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      raise Delayed::DeserializationError
    end

    def to_yaml_properties
      ['@attributes', '@database']    # add in database attribute for serialization
    end

  end
end
```

Which is just what DJ does, except I'm logging the action.

```
YAML.load Contact.first.to_yaml
# => yaml_new!!!
```

I actually get the logged output!!

So what am I doing wrong outside of my Rails app??  Is there some other way of getting this method to trigger??  I ask because I'm trying to test this in my own gem and the `yaml_new` method doesn't trigger, so my tests fail, and yet it actually does work inside Rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add  something like

```
yaml_as "tag:ruby.yaml.org,2002:B"
```

before the definition of the `self.yaml_new` method. According to the comments in yaml/tag.rb, yaml_as:

> Adds a taguri *tag* to a class, used when dumping or loading the class
>   in YAML.  See YAML::tag_class for detailed information on typing and
>   taguris.